# Request to reopen the "threatened to resign, called a bully question"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I would like this question to be re-opened.

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/65794/threatened-to-resign-accused-of-being-a-bully

1. Multiple users answered the question with varying degrees of commentary.
2. It does contain a question.  The story was necessary to give the context in which the question was asked.  If I need to reword it, give me guidance on roughly what to say to get it opened.
3. Fun is not entirely forbidden on Stack Exchange - the fact that I indicated that I thought the whole situation was somewhat humorous in retrospect does not mean I did not want others views on it.  I honestly  wanted to validate my intuition that I was engaged in a power-play by giving an ultimatum, but not bullying.

Comment: I don't think it was closed because it was 'fun'. I would have voted to close as too broad, or opinion based, as it doesn't have an answer that I can see.

Comment: Those who answered it understood the question.  What you not seeing? It is about what constitutes bullying in the workplace.

Comment: The close reason is underneath your post: "Real questions have answers. Rather than explaining why your situation is terrible, or why your boss/coworker makes you unhappy, explain what you want to do to make it better. "

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I didn't ask for the question to be reopened.

Comment: You asked whether your question was on topic, which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: If you already accepted an answer, why does it matter if the question is open or closed?

Comment: "Those who answered it understood the question" then the question probably needs clarification/simplification

Comment: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Answer (score 2):

The only sentence I can see there that is close to being a question is:

> I'm curious if bullying goes both ways.

The rest of your post is the narrative, and then your opinion. I honestly can't see a) what you are asking, and b) if I try to extrapolate from that sentence, I don't know what answer you could accept.

If I said that bullying does go both ways, what would that mean to you? Could you use that information? Same if I said it doesn't...

Comment: 1. Explicit questions are not necessary for there to be one.  2. Most words have objective meanings.  If they didn't, we couldn't communicate about anything.  I'm exploring our natural understanding of the word "bullying" in the social context of work.  The others who answered got my question.  Why cannot you?  Why do you get to police what a question is and isn't?  Status on Workplace?

Comment: "Explicit questions are not necessary for there to be one" that is not correct at all by Stack Exchange standards. Questions should be simple, & clear and inspire definitive answers.

Comment: "I'm exploring our natural understanding of the word "bullying" in the social context of work." This is not the proper place for that. There are many better suited discussion forums (heck, you can even use chat.stackexchange.com probably).

Comment: "Why do you get to police what a question is" because this is a community run site. We collectively vote etc. to decide what stays and what goes.

You seem to have assumed some definition of Stack Exchange that was never the case?

Comment: Mrsutton - in this case I didn't police anything, but had I seen your post sooner I would have. As could any member of the community. As Dorito said, this is a community where anyone can help maintain quality. My status (or reputation) here isn't that high, but like anyone else could, I thought I'd answer to help you understand the position, as I understand it.

Comment: I apologize for starting this.  I hoped someone would advise me regarding what changes needed to be made.

Answer (score 1):

The question as posed simply doesn't have a productive answer. As such it is not a good Stack Exchange question. It may be a fine topic for discussion, but this is intended to be a FAQ site, not a discussion site.  Take it to a place where it's a better fit for the site's goals.

Comment: I agree.  No one here has been able to provide an objective, reasonable definition of the requirements for questions.  It appears to me that the mob rules here.  That mentality never works for any human community.  Some core set of values or laws must be used as guides for governing, whatever that looks like.  I intend to leave workplace and may consider creating a competing site where Q&A along with free flowing discussion is allowed.

Comment: SE never wanted to be the only site people use; there are lots of others already in existence with their own styles and goals, and that's a _good_ thing.  If you are looking for solutions, SE is a good place to ask,; if you are looking for discussion or opinions any of those would be appropriate. If you have yet another approach that justifies creating a new site rather than using be if those, ***go for it***.

Comment: @mrsuttonsaiditfirst - " I intend to leave workplace and may consider creating a competing site where Q&A along with free flowing discussion is allowed." - Once you have created your site, let us know how to find it. Some of us here might like to help.

Comment: Be if -> one of. Darned auto incorrect...